# DataBase plugin in Tibco BW6

Tags: database, plugins, tibco

I try to install TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks Plug-in for Database 8.3.1 from BW toolkit.

I select the plugin from Available Software and seems that is installing(i don't get any error).

After the installation, I expect to see the new nod(activity) in Palette library, but this is not happening. I don't see new things there.

I am using Tibco BusinessWorks 6.4 trial version.

I try to download the plugin from https://edelivery.tibco.com, but it says I do not have privileges to do download.

Comment: In TIBCO BW (full licensed version) the activities (palletes) are supposed to be available irrespective if you install the BW Database Plugin or not. Maybe it's not the plugin issue but the trail version limitation

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It doesn’t have anything with using trial version.
The problem was that I installed TIBCO BW in “Program Files”(Tibco Home) with config files in “Program Data”.
It seams that is better to install somewhere where you do not need admin rights. I installed in another location and now everything in working fine now.